# Как центрировать блок по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, html5, css3

Почему не работает `vertical-align: middle`?
Как сделать так чтобы `button` был в центрирован по середине?

```css
.block_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1"></div>
<button>I wanna be in the middle :(</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот так сработает

```css
.block_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1"></div>
<button>I wanna be in the middle :(</button>
```

Но я предпочитаю так

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.block_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="block_1"></div>
<button>I wanna be in the middle :(</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы объяснить, *почему* так сработает?

Comment: vertical-align; middle имеет специфичное поведение. Оно больше похоже на `vertical-align; text-top` или `vertical-align; text-bottom`, только `middle`. Тоесть оно не будет искать элементы с блочными свойствами (`inline-block`), большими, чем тот блок **к которому применено свойство**

Comment: Короче мне тяжело нормально объяснить. Чтоб понять почему так - надо понять чем `top` отличается от `text-top` и принять тот факт что `middle` - это на самом деле как бы `text-middle`

Answer (score 2):

Так происходит, потому что по умолчанию `display: inline-block;` - `vertical-align: baseline;` (Выравнивает базовую линию текущего элемента по базовой линии родителя. Если родительский элемент не имеет базовой линии, то за нее принимается нижняя граница элемента.)

```css
.block_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1"></div>
<button>I wanna be in the middle :(</button>
```